# Is the reputation graph overlapping with recent reputation gaining posts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

[image]

I saw this change after [Standard side bar change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites?cb=1)

Any problem there?

Comment: Exactly, you are right. It's a bug that appeared a few minutes ago.

Comment: We are aware and working on a fix.

Comment: @rossipedia [We](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users) understand that, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed soon, if not already as [Bret](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314542/426671) fixed this in the latest build.