# Expand elements to fit the new sidebar

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, sidebar

There are a number of elements that go in the sidebar that seem malformed with the new width they've gained.

Site Stats (beta sites):

[image]

That looks incomplete - could the horizontal lines be expanded, or something like that?

Love this site? message:

[image]

That's still using the old sidebar width, which means it doesn't fill the whole sidebar and looks odd.

The "people chatting" chat room cards also have the avatar list cut off before it's anywhere near the end of the box - we could fit some more avatars in there.

There may be more. I assume some of these have been noticed already, but if they haven't - can we expand them please?

Comment: The "Love this site" ad and all other ads are already addressed in the [question explaining the update](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites?cb=1)... They will be slowly redesigned to fit the new space but it simply hasn't been done yet.

Comment: those things will be updated on coming release.

Comment: I find it hilarious that the previous question had the exact opposite request http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272811/is-standard-sidebar-wastage-of-space (10k sorry)

Answer (score 1):

I'm closing this because everything you mention is stuff that's already being worked on or is completed. We're well aware that some of the ad content is not going to fill the whole sidebar, and it'll be a while before everything is switched over. If you find any style bugs other than simply ads not filling the whole width, please do report them though.