# Please make Q/A part of Stack Exchange centered on a page, instead of shifted so far left

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, design

The image in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272814/193412) shows the effect of the new change which significantly decenters the core question/answer part of stack exchange in wider monitors. Notice how far left the Q/A is shifted, with the red indicating white space.

My suggestion (or bug report, depending on intent) is to keep the Q/A centered. My monitor is a widescreen and there is nearly twice as much white space on the right as compared to the left when you scroll down and look at answers further down the page.

This is disorienting and aesthetically really unpleasing.

[image]

Comment: It should be a single column layout

Comment: How do you expect this to be implemented? It is already centered... it simply looks off-center because you haven't included the sidebar... if you centered it as you request and then scroll to the part of the page with the sidebar, the entire thing will be off-center.

Comment: @Catija well step 1 might be reverting the change to the sidebar and investigating a way to better design/organize the page layout than just pushing everything left as a side effect of wanting to show more ads?

Comment: I don't get why noone ever complained about this before the recent sidebar change if it's such a big problem. It's clearly by design and a natural side-effect of the sidebar change (which already rules out the `bug` tag actually). Why stop the change and investigate into something noone ever complained about?

Answer (score 6):

It is centered. This is not a "new" issue. The page content without the sidebar has never been centered because the sidebar itself forces the main page content to be shifted to the left.

> [image]

And, because I managed to have not reloaded the SFF home page since the change went into effect, here's a side by side comparison of the difference on a screen 1440 px wide. For comparison, I've included sections with and without the sidebar and the "blank space" is made more obvious by the lovely benefit of SFF's design background:

> [image: Before change]
>   [image: After change]

The horror!

Comment: The request clearly asks for _the Q&A part_ to be centered. The image in the question leaves out the sidebar _intentionally_.

Comment: @JoshCaswell and the fact still remains that this has never before been an issue for the op and that the change is, in fact, incredibly minor. This request is pointless and goes against web design standards.

Comment: Well, the width of the content did just change. Apparently it went over some threshold of ugliness for enderland. You're perfectly welcome to disagree with the location of that threshold.