# Area 51 Share Links aren't updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, area-51, advertising

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Urban Planning]

The Area 51 ads shouldn't really look like that. It seems like the image is cropped, changing the sizes in the HTML code won't exactly fix it.

Even resizing doesn't work:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Urban Planning]

Comment: They're cropped but also smushed... interesting.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing an updated one for Latin Language Q&A right now and it seems to be rendering just fine. I wonder if there's something wrong with the Urban Planning one...

Comment: @Catija I don't know if it's just this one, but I'm sure there's other ads that are affected.

Comment: It's likely just caching. All of the Area 51 ad images have been updated. If you still see it tomorrow, let me know.

Comment: @BretCopeland Sounds good. [status-blame-caching?]

Comment: @Bret server side caching?

Comment: @ShadowWizard honestly, I have no idea. There are so many places different stuff is cached. We were trying to clear all the caches for the newsletter ads this morning and simply gave up. It's easier to let it expire on its own. FWIW, the A51 ads updated immediately for me. It could definitely be a client-side issue.

Comment: @Bret I don't see them updated either.

Comment: @Bret sorry if it sounds silly, but did you also purge the CloudFlare cache? Server side resource caching, e.g. CDN, or in your case CF, might be cruel...

Comment: @ShadowWizard we don't actually use CF for caching. When we're behind it, it's just for DDoS protection, to speed up handshakes, and potentially reduce packet transfer via their diffing system.

Comment: @Bret thanks, I just noticed a response header "Server:cloudflare-nginx" so assumed CF might also play some tricks here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard well, depends on what you're talking about. CF might actually serve cached from sstatic.net, I would have to check. It doesn't cache stuff for our main sites. The markup itself, which includes the style tag with the background image, is coming from A51 itself, which shouldn't be cached, but I could check on that. Also, see my answer below.

Comment: @ShadowWizard looks like it may in fact be caching it because it's JavaScript, and we _do_ cache that via CF. It's purged from the CDN now, so see if that clears it up for you.

Comment: @Bret actually for me it worked - was trying to find possible reasons why OP here still can't see it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer is that those have already been updated, and have been since shortly after the rollout this morning. Here's even a screenshot of the updated images:

[image]

But, it looks like it may have been cached on our CDN. We've purged it, so try it again now if you were having problems before.

If you're still seeing the old size and old image, try loading with caching disabled. In Chrome, you can hit F12 -> Network tab -> check the "Disable cache" checkbox.

If you *still* see the old size, then please post what site you're looking at and the response from http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/js?id=a51-ad-container is. For example:

```
$(function() { $('#a51-ad-container').html("\r\n\u003cstyle type=\"text/css\"\u003e\r\n#a51-ad { background: url(\"//cdn.sstatic.net/area51/Img/bg-area51-ad-commitment.png?v=2\") no-repeat bottom center; }\r\n#a51-ad, #a51-ad a { display:block; height: 250px; width: 300px; text-decoration: none; }\r\n#a51-ad table { position: relative; top: 55px; }\r\n#a51-ad-title-row { height: 95px; }\r\n#a51-ad-title { padding: 0 5px; text-align: center; font-size: 29.5px; line-height: 33.5px; font-family: Impact,\u0027Futura-CondensedExtraBold\u0027,sans-serif; color: #FBF9E2; text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000; width: 300px; vertical-align: middle; }\r\n#a51-ad-subtitle { padding:3px; text-align: center; color: white; font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; }\r\n\u003c/style\u003e\r\n\u003c!--[if lte IE 7]\u003e\r\n\u003cstyle type-\"text/css\"\u003e\r\n#a51-ad { background: url(//cdn.sstatic.net/area51/Img/bg-area51-ad-commitment.png?v=2) no-repeat bottom center; }\r\n\u003c/style\u003e\r\n\u003c![endif]--\u003e\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"a51-ad\"\u003e\r\n    \u003ca href=\"http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409/latin-language?commit=1\u0026utm_medium=ad\u0026utm_source=\u0026utm_campaign=-area51-promo\"\u003e\r\n        \u003ctable\u003e\r\n            \u003ctr id=\"a51-ad-title-row\"\u003e\u003ctd id=\"a51-ad-title\"\u003eLatin Language Q\u0026amp;A\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\r\n            \u003ctr\u003e\u003ctd id=\"a51-ad-subtitle\"\u003e79% committed\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\r\n        \u003c/table\u003e        \r\n    \u003c/a\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003cscript\u003e\r\n    if (window._a51AdUrl) {\r\n        $(\u0027#a51-ad a\u0027).each(function() { $(this).attr(\u0027href\u0027, window._a51AdUrl + (window._a51AdUrl.indexOf(\u0027?\u0027) == -1 ? \u0027?\u0027 : \u0027\u0026\u0027) + \u0027url=\u0027 + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr(\u0027href\u0027))); })\r\n    }\r\n\u003c/script\u003e"); });
```

Comment: They got screwed in another way recently.

Comment: Right now, the ads for proposals in the follow-stage are broken, while the ads for proposals in commitment and beta are working fine. And it’s not a caching issue.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft "broken" is not much to go on. When you see something broken, please post more information like screenshots and response bodies. I'll try to repro it, but so far I haven't seen a problem.

Comment: @BretCopeland: Sorry, I thought this was easily reproducable given that [others complain about it as well](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314771/2127008) and it’s visible in the question. Anyway: [This image](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/92559.png) looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UnYyG.png) (I directly handed the URL to Imgur) and it shouldn’t. Analogous images for proposals in commitment or beta look correct.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft interesting. We'll track it on this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273042/the-background-of-area-51-ads-is-incorrectly-sized

Answer (score 0):

[The announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites?cb=1) explicitly states that it's not a subject to report - they will be updated eventually:

> You'll still see some narrow 220px ads because it's going to take us a good while to update all of the old ads

Just as an example, the Lifehacks ad (which is not really relevant already, but doesn't matter :) **apparently got an update**. I've noticed it because it's in my profile :)

[image]

So the updating is clearly in progress.

Comment: But it's not simply "narrow"... it's cut off and squashed looking. It's as if they did make the change but they're still being shoved into a 220px space.

Comment: Anyway, all of the Area 51 ads should be updated at the same time... shouldn't they? They're one ad background with the site info added on top of it, like the HNQs... Staff doesn't have to make a unique ad for every HNQ... only the base ad and the autofilled text.

Comment: Hmmm... Resizing doesn't work. See the updated question.

Comment: @Ziz How is it supposed to work? The add **wasn't updated**, that's all. I have no idea why do they update partially, but at least you can see that the one which is in my answer is updated.

Comment: Wait. if the ads are auto-generated? Then why is it that not all the ads are being updated? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ziz Maybe it doesn't, though it seems that the adds updating is in progress.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Well, they still have to redo the background image for every Ad **type**... but there's only one background for all of the Area 51 ads.

Comment: Each type (follow vs commit vs beta) is a different image file that needs to be updated in both the code and the base image file itself. All of the beta sites should be using the new beta image. The follow and commit images are still being updated.

Comment: @animuson Ah, that makes sense. So each proposal has it's own dedicated image file? I thought they were auto-generated...

Comment: @Zizouz212 They are auto-generated, but based on a base stage image file. Eg the buttons at the bottom are part of the image file, and change depending on the site's stage. The site title and number of whatever is generated and placed onto that image.

Comment: @animuson Ah, that makes sense. The one for Latin Language is in Commitment phase... the one in this answer is in Beta and the one in the question is in follow. Thanks!

Comment: So we're just waiting for someone to come up, and remake that base file then?

Comment: Looks like it's already done @Zizouz212 - see Bret's answer.