# The background of Area 51 ads is incorrectly sized

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-promotion-ads

Now that [the new community ads posts have been made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272997/when-will-new-community-promotion-ad-questions-be-appearing-in-metas-for-2016/273001#273001), we need the Area 51 ads to be updated to the new size.

[image: The ad for the Hebrew Language site]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/75348.png))</sub>

Some appear to have the new size, but are not displaying correctly:

[image: The ad for the Greek Language site]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/89516.png))</sub>

[Screenshots for posterity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxdBV.png)

Comment: Interesting that when another question was asked, the adds weren't screwed that hard...

Comment: I'm reopening this because it appears to be a different issue. I haven't been able to repro yet, but we'll look into it.

Comment: For the protocol: It seems that it’s exactly the ads of proposals in the follow phase that are affected by this. In the commitment and beta phase, everything works fine.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yes. I'm attempting to post a Community Promotion Ad for a site in proposal phase and I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this, and a link to the page where you saw this would help narrow it down greatly

Comment: @rossipedia right here on this page. But if they're fixed for you then it's probably a caching issue?

Comment: Same with [Urban Planning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/88933.png) ([proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88933/urban-planning)) and [Remote Sensing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/90327.png) ([proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/geomatics-and-remote-sensing))

Comment: @rossipedia: For more reproduction, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272831/area-51-share-links-arent-updated/272837#comment887117_272837).

Comment: @BretCopeland Wasn't this supposed to be solve here? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272831/area-51-share-links-arent-updated

Comment: @Zizouz212 it turned out there were two different issues. One was fixed, and one wasn't. We're still looking at this one. The Area51 codebase isn't exactly worked on very often.

Comment: Ah, makes sense then :) Poor Area 51 got no love... Speaking of which, I see the same behaviour here as on my old question (the former dupe).

Comment: Removed duplicate as this is actually a separate issue from the "share" one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed! We hit an edge case in the way we were caching those images. Also, one of them had an incorrect format (32 bits per pixel as opposed to 24), which was causing the drawing code to blit the images incorrectly.

While we're still not serving HiDPI images for those, hopefully you shouldn't see any more of the weird sizing issues. If you do, feel free to [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) us again :)

Comment: I'm still seeing the broken Greek Language one, even with my cache disabled.

Comment: Are you referring to [this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/89516.png)? It shows correctly for me. What are you seeing?

Comment: Still like it is in the screenshots for posterity link above

Comment: Do you have a URL to the image you're seeing? And possible the URL of the page you see it on?

Comment: On this page, and it still looks like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/PxdBV.png (The Hebrew one is fixed.)

Comment: Finally fixed for me.