# Area 51 auto-created "Share This" image links constrain ads to 220 x 250px

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, share-this

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Arts and Crafts]

The default text still constrains the ads to the old sizes:

> `<a href="https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77518/arts-and-crafts?referrer=j035dwtfU9bivjBCW2knwQ2"><img src="https://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/77518.png" width="220" height="250" alt="Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Arts and Crafts" /></a>`

Note the `width="220"`

This causes the ads to look squashed.

The width constraint needs to change from 220 to 300 to reflect the new ad size:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Arts and Crafts]

> `<a href="https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77518/arts-and-crafts?referrer=j035dwtfU9bivjBCW2knwQ2"><img src="https://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/77518.png" width="300" height="250" alt="Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Arts and Crafts" /></a>`

This **may** be a dupe of [Area 51 Share Links aren't updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272831/area-51-share-links-arent-updated) but that question is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), while this issue clearly isn't fixed. And the rendered output is not the same as [The background of Area 51 ads is incorrectly sized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273042/the-background-of-area-51-ads-is-incorrectly-sized), which fills the 300 px width but still crops the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup. This was missed. Fix going out shortly, thanks for the heads up!

*edit* Okay the fix is now live