# 'Related' question on the sidebar is moved to new line from their respective upvote scores?

Tags: bug, sidebar

Not sure if this has been asked. If so please delete this post.

Since the new [standardization of sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites?cb=1), I notice 'related' question on the sidebar is moved to new line from their respective upvote scores. This seems to be a problem for long questions only though.

Is this an intended effect or it is a genuine bug?

My device is Ipad3 running IOs 6

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: [Mac OS 10.11, Safari 9, norepro](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T1CUg.png)

Comment: I'm using an iPad 2 running iOS 9.2, and it looks fine, even with long questions. Sorry I couldn't help!

Comment: Wonder if it is about iOS I am using....