# Show titles of sidebar items in tooltips

Tags: feature-request, design, tooltips, sidebar

If you mouse over just about anything on a Stack Exchange page -- buttons, post links, user cards, even timestamps -- you'll get a helpful tooltip.  If, on the main page, you mouse over the title of a question, you get the first few lines of the question in a tooltip.  This is great, and a well-established pattern -- mouse-over usually does something on SE.

There's one additional place where it would be really helpful to have such tooltips:

[image: titles in sidebar]

If your browser window isn't wide enough to fully show the sidebar, you have to scroll horizontally in order to read the titles of community events, related questions, and hot network questions.  Could we please have the full title strings in tooltips over those items as well?