# When will new Community Promotion Ad questions be appearing in Metas for 2016?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, community-promotion-ads

Now that the [new sidebar/ad size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites) has been implemented network-wide and SE designers are working diligently on remaking all of the internal ads for sites, I was expecting to see the community promotion ad questions pop up on the sites I use... but they haven't.

In a comment on that question, [Abby](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites#comment885010_272563) said:

> That's why the community ad refreshes have been delayed this time around - we had to confirm this plan, so we didn't make everybody submit a bunch of ads in the old size and then have to suddenly do it again at the new size.

As an FYI, when should we have our updated custom ads ready to go for the new season of Community Promotion Ads?

In addition, an answer that gives a brief on the updated guidelines for the ads would be much appreciated, too.

Comment: I was thinking about this recently and was going to ask it....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm the one in charge of starting up the new Community Promotion Ads. And they're actually slated to be up by the end of today!

We already have [Stack Overflow's spin on the situation up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314722/open-source-advertising-1h-2016), as they're the easiest one. The rest? The main slow point is that naturally with the update in the width of the ad space, so too do our "Example Ads for Twitter" that we run on all the community promotion ads, those need to be resized as well. I had a designer help me fix the template but it still takes a while on account of fixing up 59 separate individual images - including ones for the 5 new sites who recently graduated but after we stopped adding new threads. That was done this morning, so the rest of the time has been setting up all the posts, and soon to post them and then get them hooked up to the ad servers.

As to updates on the guidelines? They're as follows. Some of these were pointed out in the late portion of 2015, but not all sites uniformly received the update.

- Old: Size must be 220x250 -> Size must be **300x250** (or twice that, for retina)
- Old: Image filesize cannot exceed 150KB -> Filesize cannot exceed **40KB**.
- Images where the background is white or partially white, must have a 1px border of not-white around them.

> **Update** - They're all up now! Please be patient while we actually hook up the ads so nothing will be actually be running in the slots yet, but the threads are now up across the network.

Comment: Could you share the twitter template ads? They're useful for creating other themed ads, such as for chat rooms.

Comment: Also are the twitter ads retina ready? It would be nice if they were, especially if we are able to use them to make new ads.

Comment: The template contain the text, not the logos, which seems to be opposite the need here if you're trying to make ads for things not about Twitter, or ads related to the site due to the absence of the logo. Editing out the text of the corresponding sample ad on the site would probably get more effect. Building off that though, creating an ad for chat is a bit questionable since there's multiple pointers to the site's chat region, including dedicated space in the sidebar already.

Comment: For retina ads of 600x500, must the border be 1px or 2px (to redraw at 1px on standard screens)?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "not white"?

Comment: Hi, Can I ask you about When will new Community Promotion Ad questions be appearing in Metas for 2017?