# Can the community promotion Twitter ad templates be shared?

Tags: discussion, community-promotion-ads

Grace note has just updated all of the community promotion Twitter ads to the new size. In [his post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273001/256282) he mentioned using a template to make them.

Would it be possible to share the templates with us? They would be useful for making consistent site themed ads for things like chat rooms, partner sites, site blogs etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

This is the template I use, with the size and font updates from Pawel. You could get this by editing out the logo in any of the 58 sites that have the ad up, as it were, so I don't really have any valid reason not to share it. I do have a good amount of confusion as to what good it would do for you, though.

Comment: I guess it just looks nice

Comment: I thought they were more site specific before, I didn't realise they were all the same except the logo. Anyway, thanks!