# When will the dynamic "bounty" site ads update to the new size?

Tags: discussion, advertising, community-promotion-ads

As mentioned [elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites) the new size for sidebar ads is 300x250 px.

Now that the Community Promotion ads are going live, when will the dynamic bounty ads change size to match the new standard?

e.g., for [chemistry.stackexchange.com](http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/chemistry.stackexchange.com/bounty.png)

These still are 220x250 px in size.

Comment: Whenever the people who actually built it update the code to reflect the new sizes. That ad is not generated by Stack Exchange itself, but is a third-party app which utilizes the API.

Comment: Indeed.. I just hadn't noticed any other comments on MSE and thought it would be useful as a "ping." Is there another way to contact them?

Comment: The user who created it is: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/r-m He's a mod on Mathematica. You might try pinging him [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1168)?

Comment: It looks like he's already working on possibly updating the size based on comments there.