# Using search in top bar may break hat positioning

Tags: bug, design, search, top-bar, winter-bash

If you decrease browser's width to the minimum size and have to try search box you may see the following:

> [image: hat on search]

> [image: hat under inbox]

Hat is not places on user icon.

Tested on Firefox.

Comment: Confirmed similar results on chrome

Comment: How wide is minimum? As we putting the browser to less than the minimum size again? ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek this post was created before ShaWizDowArd's explanations. Even more earlier than another BR itself.

Comment: Here is an animated GIF showing the problem: https://i.imgur.com/UXAnPW9.gif

Answer (score 4):

There's a [practical, minimum supported size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites/272617#272617). Anything below that breaks on desktop view.

[image]

So... the breakage is by design. Just stop contorting the poor webpage into small spaces. Its also likely as a short event, meant for amusement, hats aren't going to get the same level of testing for... strange situations or bug fixes for situations like this

Comment: I can't stop. Sorry :)

Comment: Alexolut has tried everything possible with hats. That means a _lot_ of questions regarding the behaviour of hats. At least your exploits keep things interesting @alexolut ! :-D