# Invalid indent for site names in the footer when page width is small

Tags: bug, design, footer

Decreasing the page width makes site list in the footer aligned vertically. In this case indent between some names (which are the first names in the columns when page width is big enough) is invalid. Some strings overlap other:

> [image: vertical design hell]

Comment: pretty sure there's a minimum size for desktop SE to work right... Oddly not mentioned anywhere

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it is, indirectly. I've updated [this faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/152859) with the info.

Comment: @ShadowWizard if I need at least 1060px width for full site view, why footer changes it's behavior (horizontal to vertical view) only if page width is about 890px?

Comment: @alexolut that's a good question, but even if this is some attempt to make it look better on mobile devices or small screens, the rest of the site design will break so it's pretty much pointless.

Answer (score 2):

The full site theme is fully working as designed only where the available screen width is at least 1060 pixels.

The problem described here happens when the width is around 900 pixels.

So I really don't think that is really a bug, if you want the site to look pretty on small screen, use the mobile theme.

Comment: Where did you get 1060px size?

Comment: @alexolut https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Avm.png

Comment: This is not my fault :) And should be documented anywhere!

Comment: A developer did mention minimum width that does not cut anything is 1032 pixels: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites/272617#272617.

Comment: @alexolut what you mean "not your fault"? If you want to use the site properly and see the design as it should be, you must use proper device, with proper browser etc. For example we can't expect everything to look nice on a watch. Same way that playing games with less than the recommended specs will cause the game to break or slow down, browsing SE with small screens while still using the full site theme will cause things to not look good.

Comment: mobile view rescales well. Desktop assumes a certain minimum. Funny thing is I used to use mobile chat in google's windows 8 app for dockable chat until I got vivaldi, for that reason

Comment: I can ... if watch screen is big enough. E.g. wall watch :)